# How does jQuery’s .text() work, internally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I quickly tried to find the implementation in jQuery’s source, but only found [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/61e37d41490aed319a176c6ca7feb95e5505059c/src/manipulation.js#L33-46) which doesn’t actually seem to define it completely.

**From the jQuery Source**

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    text: function( text ) {
        if ( jQuery.isFunction(text) ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                return jQuery(this).text( text.call(this) );
            });
        }

        if ( typeof text !== "object" && text !== undefined ) {
            return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );
        }

        return jQuery.getText( this );
    },
```

Anyone know?

**Clarification:**
I know how to *use* it. I just want to know how to get the text of an element à la jQuery when jQuery isn’t available.

Comment: I edited and added the source code you refer/link to. When someone peer reviews it, it should show up.

Comment: Interesting to note that there are two different methods recommended below: The jQuery way, using Sizzle; and the native .textContent or .innerText methods — and they seem to hangle line breaks in completely opposite ways: <br /> ignored and whitespace preserved, or the opposite.

Comment: The current Sizzle appears to fall back to textContent but does not use innerText - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11153

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery.fn.text can be used for 3 different purposes, as the source you pasted clearly shows. The case you're looking for, is the third one - returning the text value of an element.

jQuery uses jQuery.text() method to get the text value of an element, and jQuery.text points to Sizzle.getText()

```
jQuery.text = Sizzle.getText;
```

And here's the definition of getText function.

```
// Utility function for retreiving the text value of an array of DOM nodes
Sizzle.getText = function( elems ) {
    var ret = "", elem;

    for ( var i = 0; elems[i]; i++ ) {
        elem = elems[i];

        // Get the text from text nodes and CDATA nodes
        if ( elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 4 ) {
            ret += elem.nodeValue;

        // Traverse everything else, except comment nodes
        } else if ( elem.nodeType !== 8 ) {
            ret += Sizzle.getText( elem.childNodes );
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cBsDN/

Comment: Sizzle now appears to use `elem.textContent` if this is available.

Answer (score 10):

```
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XnL7H/1/

Comment: Huh, seems this isn’t how jQuery/Sizzle do it, but that’s still really interesting and still answers the spirit of the question — thanks for sharing!

Comment: I wonder why it isn't like that in Sizzle...because it's obviously slower they way they do the recursive summing of texts.

Comment: innerText and textContent are not standards and work differently in different browsers. They mostly work ok, but e.g. you might end up in situation where there is a lot more space / special characters in the string than should be. As browsers format the child nodes tags in different way.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the Sizzle getText method:

```
// Utility function for retreiving the text value of an array of DOM nodes
Sizzle.getText = function( elems ) {
    var ret = "", elem;

    for ( var i = 0; elems[i]; i++ ) {
        elem = elems[i];

        // Get the text from text nodes and CDATA nodes
        if ( elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 4 ) {
            ret += elem.nodeValue;

        // Traverse everything else, except comment nodes
        } else if ( elem.nodeType !== 8 ) {
            ret += Sizzle.getText( elem.childNodes );
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get an element in JavaScript with out jQuery.

```
var el = document.getElementById("my-element");
```

And then you just have to use two properties that are available for each element `innerText` and `innerHTML`.  So to get the text you use:

```
var text = el.innerText;
```

Or to get HTML, you do:

```
var html = el.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. FWIW, patricks's suggestion would be more cross-browser, an innerText is not supported by Firefox: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the different of createTextNode and createElement, you can understand how to jquery.text work.

text function create a DOM text node. The browser will tread the value of node as text.