# Equivalent of innerHTML for text

Tags: javascript, dom, textnode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does jQuery’s .text() work, internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023432/how-does-jquerys-text-work-internally)

I'm looking for the text equivalent of `innerHTML`, i.e.

```
<p>Hello, <i>World!</i></p>
```

then `innerText(p)` should return `Hello, World!`.

Note: I'm aware of jQuery's `text()` function. I want to know how it is implemented so I can do special handling on some nodes, like inserting extra white space.

Comment: Remotely related to ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1359469)

Comment: While this is not *exactly* the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023432, it certainly is close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
var getInnerText = function (element) {
    var nodes = element.childNodes,
        i = 0,
        len = nodes.length,
        text = '';
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3 || nodes[i].nodeType === 4) {
            // 3 means text node, 4 means cdata
            text += nodes[i].nodeValue;
        } else {
            text += getInnerText(nodes[i]);
        }
    }
    return text;
};
```

then: `var innerText = getInnerText(myElement);`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LWqV/2/)

Comment: I'm not sure about the `text` parameter. I feel that you duplicate part of the text content.

Comment: you're right. now this should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source for getText(): Taken from question: [How does jQuery’s .text() work, internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023432/how-does-jquerys-text-work-internally)

```
// Utility function for retreiving the text value of an array of DOM nodes
Sizzle.getText = function( elems ) {
    var ret = "", elem;

    for ( var i = 0; elems[i]; i++ ) {
        elem = elems[i];

        // Get the text from text nodes and CDATA nodes
        if ( elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 4 ) {
            ret += elem.nodeValue;

        // Traverse everything else, except comment nodes
        } else if ( elem.nodeType !== 8 ) {
            ret += Sizzle.getText( elem.childNodes );
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use  innerText property instead of innetHTML.

Example...

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="myP">Sample Text inside a <b>p</b> element <a href="#"> this is a link </a></p>
<button onclick="alert(myP.innerHTML);">InnerHTML</button>
<button onclick="alert(myP.innerText);">InnerText</button>
</body>
</html>
```