# how parameter inside function works?

Tags: jquery

html

```
<p>This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<button>Add</button>
```

jquery

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text(function(i,origText){
      return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + i + ")"; 
    });
  });
```

I would like to know **origText** is not called outside function but it is returning the value. How?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zBgRb/)

Comment: Dive into jQuery's source!

Answer (score 2):

[As docs says](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)

> function(index, text)
>
> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

And [How does jQuery’s .text() work, internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023432/how-does-jquerys-text-work-internally)

Answer (score 2):

The actual method `text` takes a function as a parameter. The function passed to `text` may contain two parameters, the first of which receives the index, the second the original text.

Comment: text() function must contain two parameteres?

Comment: The function *passed* to the text method may contain two parameters, in your case i and origText.

Comment: @C-Link No.Not necessarily.See the others methods in docs.You can use it with various no.of params.

Answer (score 0):

Function `text` does some preparations about input nodes and then runs callback provided by user (your function), and it pass to your callback this two arguments (which prepared on "some preparations") step. If you want *exact* code, you can read jQuery source.

Answer (score 0):

In simple:

```
text(function(whatever){
      return whatever; // returns the text what is the text it has.
    });
```

In your example **p** has text : This is a bold paragraph.

return whatever will return your text : This is a bold paragraph.