# How to get innerHTML for each button and display in text box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just some of the HTML, but it's the whole alphabet. I want to click any button and that letter will go in the text box. Do i have to create getelementbyID for each button or can I create some kind of loop?
html - this is the html and it is basically the alphabet.

```
<div id="alpha" >
    <br/>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="w" class="letters" onclick="theclick()">W</button>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
    </div>
     <div align="center">
        <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
    </div>
     <div align="center">
        <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
    </div>


    **THIS IS THE JAVASCRIPT I HAVE. I only have the onclick function for button "w" for testing**
```

javascript - this is the javascript, it's not working but want to do some kind of loop to make it a more simple javascript code

```
<script>

    function theclick() {

        var x = document.getElementByClassName("letters").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("textbox").value = x;
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: Yeah I've used it but was seeing if it's possible to just use javascript, or maybe regex would be included in this? As long as it works :)

Comment: This is basically how jQuery does it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023432/how-does-jquery-s-text-work-internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I'd suggest is the following, using plain JavaScript:

```js
// creating a named function to act as the event-handler:
function buttonOutput() {

  // to support older browsers you may need to declare
  // your variables with 'var' rather than 'let';
  // here we cache the textarea, via its id attribute:
  let textarea = document.querySelector('#result');

  // and here we update the textContent of that
  // textarea to the existing textContent with the
  // addition of the newly-clicked element (the
  // 'this' is the <button> element and is passed
  // from the EventTarget.addEventListener() method)
  // after calling String.prototype.trim() on that
  // textContent (to remove leading and trailing
  // white-space):
  textarea.textContent += this.textContent.trim();
}


// here we retrieve the <button> elements with the class
// of 'letters' from the document:
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.letters'),

// here we convert the Array-like NodeList into an Array,
// using Array.from():
  buttonArray = Array.from(buttons);

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// Array of <button> elements:
buttonArray.forEach(

  // 'button' is the current array-element of the Array
  // over which we're iterating; here we bind the
  // buttonOutput() function as the event-handler for
  // the 'click' event (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses in the function name):
  button => button.addEventListener('click', buttonOutput)
);
```

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
}
div > button {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha">
  <div>
    <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="w" class="letters" onclick="theclick()">W</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="y" class="letters">Y</button>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wo35kjz7/).

The above snippet leans heavily towards using ES6 features, such as `let`, `Array.from()` and Arrow functions; an ES5 alternative – compatible with older browsers – follows:

```js
// creating a named function to act as the event-handler:
function buttonOutput() {

  // 'let' changed to 'var':
  var textarea = document.querySelector('#result');

  textarea.textContent += this.textContent.trim();
}


// here we retrieve the <button> elements with the class
// of 'letters' from the document:
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.letters'),

  // here we convert the Array-like NodeList into an Array,
  // using Function.prototype.call() and Array.prototype.slice():
  buttonArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons);

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// Array of <button> elements:
buttonArray.forEach(function(button) {
  // button is the current Array-element of the
  // Array over which we're iterating.

  // here we assign the buttonOutput() function
  // as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  button.addEventListener('click', buttonOutput)
});
```

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
}
div > button {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha">
  <div>
    <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="w" class="letters" onclick="theclick()">W</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="y" class="letters">Y</button>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wo35kjz7/1).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/for).
- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with jQuery would be:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.letters').on('click', function() {
    $('#textbox').text( $('#textbox').text()+$(this).text() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="alpha" >
  <div align="center">
    <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="w" class="letters">W</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Pure JS

```js
var letters = document.getElementsByClassName("letters");

var addLetter = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML,
      thisVal = this.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = val + thisVal;
};

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  letters[i].addEventListener('click', addLetter, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="alpha" >
  <div align="center">
    <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="w" class="letters">W</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LoLo, I've added a pure JS solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Or a Vanilla JS solution would be this:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#alpha button");

for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  var btn = buttons[i];
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("textbox").value += this.innerHTML;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha">
  <div align="center">
    <button id="q" class="letters">Q</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="w" class="letters">W</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="e" class="letters">E</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="r" class="letters">R</button>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="t" class="letters">T</button>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="textbox">
```