# jQuery .text() changes my h1 to a normal text after passing a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this:

```
<li id="machine" ><h1>Machine</h1></li>
<li id="player"><h1>Player</h1></li>
```

Showing this:

[image: html after the jQuery]

when I use jQuery to change the text to a number like this:

```
$("#machine").text(1);
$("#player").text(2);
```

it will change my `h1` to normal tex like this:

[image: html after the jQuery]

How do I keep the h1 to be h1 after passing a number??

Comment: What does your raw HTML look like?

Comment: Place the id on the h1..

Comment: You are not selecting the h1 with that selector. You want `#machine h1` or you can do what @Keith Said and put the id on the `h1` element

Comment: ***[Strongly Related: How does jQuery’s .text() work, internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5023432/1026459)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to target the `<h1>` directly, otherwise it will remove all tags within the `#machine` or `#player` divs.

```js
$("#machine h1").text(1);
$("#player h1").text(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="machine"><h1>Machine</h1></li>
<li id="player"><h1>Player</h1></li>
```

Alternatively, put the id directly on the `<h1>` tags

```js
$("#machine").text(1);
$("#player").text(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><h1 id="machine">Machine</h1></li>
<li><h1 id="player">Player</h1></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`text()` replaces the complete contents of the tag/class/ID it's applied to, in your case this includes the `h1`tags, which are *inside*  (i.e. contents of) the `#machine` and `#player`elements.

But you can apply your jQuery to "#machine h1" to avoid that:

```
$("#machine h1").text(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can instead use the html method  $("#machine").html("<\h1> 1 </h1>");